# Laravel 4 eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have a `User` model, a `Recipe` model, and a `Cookbook` model.

A User can 'own' many recipes. **(User -OneToMany- Recipe)**

A user has 'only one' Cookbook. **(User -OneToOne- Cookbook)**

Recipes that a user owns belong to his Cookbook.
One Recipe can belong to many Cookbook. (Recipe sharing) **(Cookbook -ManyToMany- Recipe)**

Many Users may LIKE Many Recipe. **(User -ManyToMany- Recipe)**

Many Users can follow Many Cookbook. **(User -ManyToMany- Cookbook)**

One User can have many friends who are Users **(User -OneToMany- User)**

---

What I want to do is load recipes for the currently logged in user.

I want to load *the recipes owned by his friends* and the recipes of *all the cookbooks the logged in user is following*.

---

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function friends() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
    }

    public function cookbook() {
        return $this->hasOne('Cookbook', 'owner_id', 'id');
    }

    public function recipes() {
        return $this->hasMany('Recipe', 'owner_id', 'id');
    }

    public function followedCookbooks() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Cookbook','cb_followers', 'follower_id', 'cb_id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Recipe extends Eloquent() {
    public function owner() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'owner_id', 'id');
    }

    public function cookbooks() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Cookbook', 'cb_recipes', 'recipe_id', 'cb_id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Cookbook extends Eloquent() {
    public function owner() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'owner_id', 'id');
    }

    public function recipes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Recipe', 'cookbooks_recipes', 'cookbook_id', 'recipe_id');
    }

    public function followers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'cb_followers', 'cb_id', 'follower_id');
    }
}
```

---

What I did is this:

```
$user = Auth::user();

$friends = $user->friends();
$cookbooks = $user->followedCookbooks();

$recipes = array();

foreach($friends as $friend) {
    $recipe = $friend->recipes();
    array_push($recipes, $recipe);
}

foreach($cookbooks as $cookbook) {
    $cbRecipes = $cookbook->recipes()
    foreach($cbRecipes as $cbRecipe) {
        array_push($recipes, $cbRecipe);
    }
}
```

But this method would run a lot of SQL queries. How can I use eager loading to reduce the number of queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$user = Auth::user();
$recipesFriends = $user->friends()->with('friends.recipes')->get();
$recipesCookbooks = $user->with('followedCookbooks')->with('followedCookbooks.recipes')->get();
```

If you want to go a bit further you can take a look at this answer: [How to list out all items in a nested table in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258056/how-to-list-out-all-items-in-a-nested-table-in-laravel)

Comment: I used a profiler to check the queries that were being run. The second line for `$recipesFriends` ran 4 queries out of which one was `select * from users`. I would never want this query to run because it would return a huge dataset when there are many users registered.

So I modified your method a bit and used:

`$recipesFriends = $user->friends()->with('friends.recipes')->get();`

This eliminated the `select * from users` query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$userData = Auth::user()->load('cookbook.recipes')
                        ->load('friends.cookbook.recipes');
```

If you want to load friends recipes in a different variable then you may try this:

```
$userData = Auth::user()->load('cookbook.recipes')
                        ->load('friends.cookbook.recipes');
$friendsData = $userData->friends;
```